# Remove element via $scope when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm very new to angular and I was trying some things out.
I've created a controller that shows (toggles) a menu. In the menu there are a few li's with some directives. One of them has `ng-click="erase()"`. When clicking it, I would like the element itself to be removed (deleted). It is possible to do that? In jQuery it was, I think: `element.remove();`

Here is my code:

```
<div ng-controller="DeathrayMenuController">
  <button ng-click="toggleMenu()">Toggle Menu</button>
  <ul ng-show="menuState">
    <li ng-click="stun()">Stun</li>
    <li ng-click="disintegrate()">Disintegrate</li>
    <li ng-click="erase()">Erase from history</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The `ng-click="erase()"` should remove the entire `li` from the `ul`.

And here is my code:

```
$scope.erase = function(){
  console.log($scope);
};
```

Hope someone could land me a hand. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove elements, you can use the `ng-if` directive.  This will remove the element when the expression is false.

Here's an example:

```
$scope.erase = function() {
    $scope.erased = true;
}

<li ng-click="erase()" ng-if="!erased">Erase from history</li>
```

In Angular, your JavaScript shouldn't manipulate the DOM.  Instead, your JavaScript manipulates the `$scope`, and the directives manipulate the DOM.